# self.bell() creates a RecursionError

Tags: python, audio, tkinter

I am working on a password manager, fragmented in several classes. When a certain condition is not met, I want a bell sound to notify the user. In a simpler version of the code, I used the good old self.bell() with no problem (all the code under one class - not good, hence the upgraded version).
In the upgraded code, I get a recursion error.

I've been through everything I could think of, no joy. I can't seem to find any case close enough to mine on the various forums out there.
I use pycharm 2019.1.3, on windows7.

Main file:

```
from class_createNewPassword import *
from class_searchDatabase import *
from class_updateDatabase import *


class display(Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # main window
        Tk.__init__(self, master)
        self.title('Password Manager')

        buttonCreate = ttk.Button(self, text='Create a new password', command=createNewPassword)
        buttonCreate.grid(column=0, row=0)

        buttonSearch = ttk.Button(self, text='Search the database', command=SearchDatabase)
        buttonSearch.grid(column=1, row=2)

        buttonUpdate = ttk.Button(self, text='Update the database', command=UpdateDatabase)
        buttonUpdate.grid(column=2, row=4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
app = display()
app.mainloop()
```

File where the problem is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from class_makePassword import *


class createNewPassword(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        createWindow = tk.Toplevel()
        createWindow.title('Create a password')

        Toplevel.connection = sqlite3.connect("mdp - Copy.db")
        Toplevel.cursor = Toplevel.connection.cursor()
        self.connection = Toplevel.connection
        self.cursor = Toplevel.cursor

        #bunch of tkinter variables and stuff, and some functions not related to the issue


    def savePassword(self, condition):

        if condition:  #writes data in the DB, works well
            pass
        else:
            print("problem")
            self.bell()  #problem is here
```

I get this error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "I:\01 Programs\01 On the way\SQL\password manager with classes\class_createNewPassword.py", line 249, in savePassword
self.bell()
File "F:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 783, in bell
self.tk.call(('bell',) + self._displayof(displayof))
File "F:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2101, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.tk, attr)
File "F:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2101, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.tk, attr)
File "F:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2101, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.tk, attr)
[Previous line repeated 493 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?
Thanks.

Comment: It would help if your [mcve] didn't require an external database. You can just hard-code an acceptable password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is that your `createNewPassword` class inherits from `Tk` but you don't call `Tk.__init__` to properly initialize the class.

I can't see any reason at all why you want to inherit from Tk. Instead, inherit from `Toplevel` and properly initialize it:

```
class createNewPassword(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.title('Create a password')
        ...

    def savePassword(self, condition):

        if condition:
            pass
        else:
            self.bell()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought it might be something of that kind. I'm not really comfortable with the inheritance thing, so that's what I have to work on.